# JSON Transformation with data manipulation using Apache NiFi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt, hortonworks-dataflow

I want to do some basic transformation to my below sample JSON, I want to change the value of the timeStamp tag to date format and want to add a new tag `created_ts` with value of `current_timestamp` to the my expected JSON output using NiFi.

**Sample JSON**:

```
{"name": "SAMPLE_NAME","timeStamp": "1477307252000","value": "-0.06279052","quality": "1090"}
```

**Expected JSON:**

```
{"name": "SAMPLE_NAME","timeStamp": "2016-11-08 14:46:13.674","value": "-0.06279052","quality": "1090","created_ts":"2016-11-08 14:46:13.674"}
```

Can you please help with the detail steps to follow in Apache NiFi/HDF.

Comment: I am able to add new field created_ts using jolt, but still  struggling with how to convert  "timeStamp": "1477307252000" to "timeStamp": "2016-11-08 14:46:13.674" format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

data transformation not implemented.

check the official doc:

https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt#stock-transforms

**Stock Transforms**

The Stock transforms are:

```
shift       : copy data from the input tree and put it the output tree
default     : apply default values to the tree
remove      : remove data from the tree
sort        : sort the Map key values alphabetically ( for debugging and human readability )
cardinality : "fix" the cardinality of input data.  Eg, the "urls" element is usually a List, 
                    but if there is only one, then it is a String
```

Currently, all the Stock transforms just effect the "structure" of the data.

**To do data manipulation, you will need to write Java code.**

If you write your Java "data manipulation" code to implement the Transform interface, then you can insert your code in the transform chain.

---

**So, to complete your task I see two main variants:**

---

**V1:**

Use the sequence of following processors:

`EvaluateJsonPath -> UpdateAttributes -> AttributesToJSON`

in `EvaluateJsonPath` define for each field attributes with expressions like `$.name`, `$.timeStamp`, ...

in `UpdateAttributes` convert the format of `timeStamp` and define new attributes:

```
attribute  |   value/expression
-----------------------------------------------------------
timeStamp  |   timeStamp:format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
created_ts |   now():format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
```

in `AttributesToJSON` define `Attributes List` to be stored as json object into file content

---

**V2:** use `ExecuteScript` processor with following code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def ff = session.get()
if(!ff)return
ff = session.write(ff, {rawIn, rawOut->
    // transform streams into reader and writer
    rawIn.withReader("UTF-8"){reader->
        rawOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){writer->
            //parse reader into Map
            def json = new JsonSlurper().parse(reader)
            //change/set values
            json.timeStamp = new Date(json.timeStamp as Long).format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
            json.created_ts = new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
            //write changed object to writer
            new JsonBuilder(json).writeTo(writer)
        }
    }
} as StreamCallback)
session.transfer(ff, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Comment: can we do  data transformation using other nifi processors ?

Comment: @nilesh1212, modified the response

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I am trying out v1 but its seems like EvaluateJsonPath is not at all changing my json. I have set right field attributes

Comment: @nilesh1212, `EvaluateJsonPath` just extracts json attributes to flowfile attributes,  with `UpdateAttributes` you can change flow file attributes, and `AttributesToJSON` will build you a new json message from flow file attributes

Comment: When I do data provenance on EvaluateJsonPath, UpdateAttribute and AttributeToJson I am able to see the expected values, but my last flow is PutFile, PutFile is not writing the modified json's. Flow is as follows ->` ConsumerKafka -> SplitJson (to split json into single line as I am getting json array { data [ {"name":....} ,{"name":..}])  ->EvaluateJsonPath -> UpdateAttributes->AttributesToJson -> PutFile`

Comment: did you set  `Destination = flowfile-content` in `AttributesToJson` ? what do you see after `AttributesToJson` ?

Comment: Thank you so much.. after setting Destination = flowfile-content it is working as expected. You are hero :)